# C# - After maximizing my form, the width & height values are returned wrong

Tags: c#

I'm using fullscreen by setting

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

After executing it, I want to get the new width and height of the form, but when I use this.width & this.height, it just returns the values that were set *before* maximizing.

Here's my code:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
g.DrawImage(app.Properties.Resources.bg, 0, 0, Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width, Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height);
```

Comment: possibly you need [ActualWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ActualHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't see where you are using this.Width and this.Height.  Where are you calling this code?  Does your form have a border?  Post code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: That code is the edited one after Graffitos answer. Before I tried it normally with this.Width

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to recreate your issue. I just made a quick program with a `Form` (initially 300x300), a `Button`, and a TextBox. It works as expected.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        textBox1.Text = this.Width + " " + this.Height;
    }
}
```

My `textBox` (textBox1) definitely does not display "300 300"

**Edit**: Based on your updated answer and your comments below, try this and see if it works as expected (maybe also see if manually inputting width and height works?):

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
int width = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width;
int height = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;
g.DrawImage(app.Properties.Resources.bg, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you aren't getting the height and width before maximizing? Or storing them beforehand and forgetting to re-set them?

Comment: Yes, I'm a 100% sure, it is absolutely impossible

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the relevant code?

Comment: I would make a call between your two lines to the height and width to see if they even print the correct values (or debug, whichever is easier).  
This is indeed strange otherwise...

Comment: I've made some research now, the code returns the correct values for screen.getWorkingArea(this) if I use Console.WriteLine(screen.getWorkingArea(this));, but still the code doesn't draw correctly

Comment: My only suggestion would be to assign Screen.GetWorkingArea(this) to 2 variables and use the variables instead. I will add an edit to my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

When form is maximized, Get its width and height from [Screen.WorkingArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) size.

Don't use:

```
Screen.GetWorkingArea(this)
```

but:

```
Screen.WorkingArea
```

Comment: WinForms application?

Comment: Did you execute a form.Show() before ?

Comment: No, the form appears perfectly normal, do I have to do this?

Comment: No, it was in case you get the form size before calling the Show().

Comment: I realized that you were using Screen.GetWorkingArea(this). replace it by **Screen.WorkingArea**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but only with .net core winforms.
Despite maximising screen it used previous values if I used this.width and this.height.

this.Width = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width;
this.Height = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;
Fixed it